# Why is there a Segmentation fault from trying to add to count and printf?

Tags: c, list, queue

```
#include <stdio.h>                         /* the "QueueTypes.h" file, */
#include <stdlib.h>                   /* given above on lines 1:15, is */
#include "QueueImplementation.c"   

void main(void){
    Queue *que;
    ItemType *num;
    num = 0;
    InitializeQueue(que);
    int count = 0;
    int check;
    int i;

    if(Empty(que) != 1){
        count = count + 1;
    }
    printf("%d", count); <- segmentation fault

    if(Remove(que, num) != 0){
        count = count + 1; <- segmentation fault
}
```

These are the parts of the program that keep getting segmentation faults. Am I illegally accessing anything?

this is queueimplementation.c. When i remove the lines that are being pointed out, the program works fine and returns errors as normal.

```
/*   ------------< begin file "QueueImplementation.c" >------------   */

   #include <stdio.h>                         /* the "QueueTypes.h" file, */
   #include <stdlib.h>                   /* given above on lines 1:15, is */
   #include "QueueInterface.h"          /* included in "QueueInterface.h" */
                                             /* on line 3 of Program 7.4. */

   void SystemError(char *errorMsg) {fprintf(stderr,errorMsg);}

   void InitializeQueue(Queue *Q)
   {
      Q->Front = NULL;
      Q->Rear  = NULL;
   }

 /* -------------------- */

   int Empty(Queue *Q)
   {
      return (Q->Front == NULL);
   }
 /* -------------------- */

   int Full(Queue *Q)   
   {                     /* we assume an already constructed queue, Q, is */
      return 0;              /* not full, since it could potentially grow */
   }                                             /* as a linked structure */

/* -------------------- */

   int Insert(ItemType R, Queue *Q)
   {   
      QueueNode *Temp;
                                                   /* attempt to allocate */
      Temp = (QueueNode *) malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));       /* a new node */

      if (Temp == NULL) {               /* Temp = NULL signals allocation */
         SystemError("system storage is exhausted");           /* failure */
     return 0;
      } else {
         Temp->Item = R;
         Temp->Link = NULL;
         if ( Q->Rear == NULL ) {
            Q->Front = Temp;
            Q->Rear = Temp;
         } else {
            Q->Rear->Link = Temp;
            Q->Rear = Temp;
         }
      }
      return 1;
   }

/* -------------------- */

   int Remove(Queue *Q, ItemType *F)
   {   
      QueueNode *Temp;

      if (Q->Front == NULL) {
         SystemError("attempt to remove item from empty Queue");
     return 0 ;
      } else {
         *F = Q->Front->Item;
         Temp = Q->Front;
         Q->Front = Temp->Link;
         free(Temp);
         if (Q->Front == NULL) Q->Rear = NULL;
     return 1;
      }
   }

/* -------------------- */
```

Comment: I'm skeptical that it's those lines causing the segfault. Can you provide the implementation of `QueueImplementation.c`?

Comment: Your segmentation faults are not occurring in `printf()` or while incrementing the `count` integer. The most likely problem is that you haven't understood what happens in `QueueImplementation.c`.

Comment: i will add QueueImplementation.c in, but the program works fine when i take away those lines

Comment: The reason you get an exception is because `que` pointer is left uninitialized. Look up "pass by value" for an explanation.

Comment: Never `#include` implementation (aka ".c") files!

Comment: I'm executing the code now and it only happens when i try to print outside of the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized the pointer `que` when you pass it to `InitializeQueue()`.

A better implementation might be to pass a pointer to the pointer `que` (i.e. a `Queue**`) to `InitializeQueue()`

```
void InitializeQueue(Queue **Q)
{
   *Q = malloc(sizeof**Q); // set aside memory for your queue
   Q->Front = NULL;
   Q->Rear  = NULL;
}
```

And call it like this

```
Queue *que;
InitializeQueue(&que);
```

If you can't change the implementation of `QueueImplementation.c`, then call `malloc` before the function call, like so:

```
Queue *que = malloc(sizeof*que);
InitializeQueue(que);
```

Or don't use heap allocation at all (my recommendation):

```
Queue que; // note that this is not a pointer
InitializeQueue(&que); // we have to take the address of it
```

Just note that with the above option, `que` can only be legally accessed within the function that defined it. However, this shouldn't affect you since you define it in `main`, so it will exist for the lifetime of your program.

As for both `malloc` options, remember to call `free()` once you finish using it.

You also fail to initialize `num` anywhere before you pass it to `Remove()`. You should fix it similarly.

You might consider using a debugger such as `valgrind`. Segmentation faults don't always occur (if they occur at all) at the same line of code that caused it and can be unreliable as a way of error checking.

---

P.S. It's sufficient to use `if (Empty(que))` instead of `if (Empty(que) != 1)` because expressions are "true" when they evaluate to a non-zero integer. It's arguably safer because all "true" values don't have to be `1`.

P.P.S. Don't `#include` `.c` files. Include the `.h` file and compile the `.c` file with your main program. If you're using `gcc`, then

```
gcc myprogram.c QueueImplementation.c
```

Other compilers use the same syntax (there's probably an exception somewhere but I haven't encountered it).

Comment: i don't think i can change anything in the QueueImplementation.c as it is from a textbook question.

Comment: @kyletruong Then initialize it before you call that function. I amended my answer to show how you'd do this.

Comment: alright it seems to be working although i have more bugs in the rest of my program to fix. Thank you very much!

Comment: @kyletruong If this answer helped you, be sure to mark it as the correct one by clicking the check mark underneath its score.

Answer (score 1):

In C, when you just declare a pointer `Queue *`, it doesn't magically point to a new "valid" instance of Queue. In fact, it points to a random location in memory which most likely doesn't contain anything that makes sense to you.

To simplify, in your code you are doing:

- Get me a pointer que, I don't care where it points to.
- Put { NULL, NULL } to where the pointer points to.

So you are writing { NULL, NULL } to a random part of system memory.

This is not how you do it. Look at the example Luddite has provided.

And additionally, please read this article to understand what is going on here:

https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node10.html

Comment: Ok thanks for the read. I need to continue to educate myself on this.

Comment: @kyle Pointers are tricky, really understanding them takes time. You are on the right path.